# How do I go to a cell to change the value?

Tags: vba, excel

I have made some 'change' buttons that need to go to the cell which has been found in the Vlookup as shown down here.

I can only find codes which go to a given range.

```
Private Sub CommandButton6_Click()

Dim status As Variant

status = WorksheetFunction.VLookup( _
        (Sheets("Gegevens").Range("B3")), _
         Sheets("bestand totaal").Range("J2:W9996"), 14, False)

End Sub
```

Comment: I'm not sure what you're asking. Your code appears to return the vlookup value, not "go to a given range." --- so what is it that you're trying to achieve?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After you find `status`, through your `VLookup`, you can use the `Find` function to search through the `VLookup` Range where the value was found.

I've added 2 `Range` variables, `Rng` for the `VLookup` range, and `RngFind` for the `Find`.

**Code**

```
Private Sub CommandButton6_Click()

Dim status As Variant
Dim Rng As Range
Dim RngFind As Range

Set Rng = Sheets("bestand totaal").Range("J2:W9996")
status = WorksheetFunction.VLookup((Sheets("Gegevens").Range("B3").Value), Rng, 14, False)

Set RngFind = Rng.Find(What:=status, LookIn:=xlValues, Lookat:=xlWhole, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:=xlNext, MatchCase:=True)
RngFind.Parent.Activate ' activate the worksheet, in case the VLookup Range is not the active sheet
RngFind.Select ' select the range (cell) where Find was set to true

End Sub
```

Comment: @Mcnanny have you tested the code in my answer above ? does it do hat you intended in your post ?

Comment: @Mcnanny your'e welcome, please mark as "answer" , blu clickin on the **V** next to my answer (it will turn green), and you get +2 points

Comment: @Mcnanny where ? can you send me the link to your new post ?

Comment: I'm using the code now with index match instead of vlookup and it gives an error at this part of the code:Set RngFind = Rng.Find(What:=behandel, LookIn:=xlValues, Lookat:=xlWhole, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:=xlNext, MatchCase:=True)
    RngFind.Parent.Activate ' activate the worksheet, in case the VLookup Range is not the active sheet
    RngFind.Select

Comment: @Mcnanny this is something entirely different than your post (and the answer I gave you here). Please open a new post, add your code, describe what you are tryigng to achieve, and other users (besides me) will be able to assist you

Comment: I've made a new post with title "How do I go to a cell (found with index match) to change the value?"  I tried to tagg you but i'm not sure if it works

Answer (score 1):

maybe you're after this

```
Private Sub CommandButton6_Click()
    Dim status As Variant

    status = Application.Match(Sheets("Gegevens").Range("B3"), _
                               Sheets("bestand totaal").Range("J2:J9996"), False) '<--| try and get the index of 'Sheets("Gegevens").Range("B3")' value in 'Sheets("bestand totaal").Range("J2:J9996")' range

    If Not IsError(status) Then '<--| if value successfully found
        With Sheets("bestand totaal") '<--| reference "target" sheet
            .Activate '<--| activate it
            .Range("W2:W9996").Cells(status, 1).Select <--| select corresponding value in column "W"
        End With
    End If
End Sub
```